# Conversion of R matrices to armadillo is really slow

Tags: c++, r, matrix, rcpp, armadillo

**An Observation**

For medium-size matrices, the overheads on passing matrices from R to C++ are massively slower for `arma::mat` types than for `NumericMatrix` types.    Like taking around 250x as long. Here's a minimal example

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double test_nm( NumericMatrix X ) {
  return 0.0 ;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double test_arma( mat X ) {
  return 0.0 ;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double test_nm_conv( NumericMatrix X ) {
  mat X_arma = as<mat>( X ) ; 
  return 0.0 ;
}
```

Then, in R:

```
XX <- matrix( runif( 10000 ), 2000, 50 )
microbenchmark( test_nm( XX ), test_arma( XX ), ( XX ) )

Unit: microseconds
               expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
        test_nm(XX)    5.541   16.154   16.0781   17.577   18.876   48.024   100
      test_arma(XX) 1280.946 1337.706 1404.0824 1361.237 1389.476 3385.868   100
   test_nm_conv(XX) 1277.417 1338.835 1393.4888 1358.128 1386.101 4355.533   100
```

So just passing a matrix as an `arma::mat` type is around 250x slower than `NumericMatrix`.  That's crazy!  So...

**Questions arising**

1. What's going on?  Why is `mat` *so* much slower than `NumericMatrix`?
2. Is there a good way to deal with this?  I've got a problem where I need to use an `arma::mat` for some fairly simple matrix algebra in a function that gets called a lot of times.  I'm currently using `arma` types throughout, and my code is *much* slower than I expected (that's how I ended up cooking up the dumb examples above).  A speed penalty of 250x is such a big deal that I'm about to rewrite large sections of code to use `NumericMatrix` types throughout.  In fact, I might end up writing my own matrix multiplication function for `NumericMatrix` and abandon `arma` types altogether.  But before I do, are there any better solutions?

(Although I guess another way to read this is not that `arma::mat` is slow to convert from R types, but that the `NumericMatrix` type is amazingly efficient!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this creates a new Armadillo matrix then copies the contents of your numeric matrix.

To cast the NumericMatrix to type arma::mat, you should use the following:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double test_const_arma( const mat& X ) { 
  return 0.0 ;
}
```

Speed comparison on my machine:

```
microbenchmark( test_const_arma( XX ), test_nm( XX ), test_arma( XX ), test_nm_conv( XX ))
## Unit: microseconds
##                 expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
##  test_const_arma(XX)  1.852  2.381  3.69014  2.7885  4.3490  11.994   100
##          test_nm(XX)  1.925  2.455  3.47679  2.8535  3.5195  21.222   100
##        test_arma(XX) 68.593 71.212 83.63055 73.4555 98.8070 278.981   100
##     test_nm_conv(XX) 68.700 70.983 80.55983 73.1705 82.2665 183.484   100
```

Comment: can you please take a short look at this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43962398/update-rcppnumericmatrix-passed-by-reference-using-rcpparmadillo-subset)? I appreciate it.